# Cannot verify the written value in a mocked output stream

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following method in my **TcpTransport** class:

```
public synchronized void send(Envelope envelope) throws IOException {
    ensureSocketOpen();
    String envelopeString = envelopeSerializer.serialize(envelope);

    if (traceWriter != null &&
            traceWriter.isEnabled()) {
        traceWriter.trace(envelopeString, TraceWriter.DataOperation.SEND);
    }

    try {
        byte[] envelopeBytes = envelopeString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(envelopeBytes);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert the serialized envelope to a UTF-8 byte array", e);
    }
}
```

And a test for it:

```
// Arrange
TcpTransport target = getAndOpenTarget(); // gets a valid instance
Envelope envelope = mock(Envelope.class);
String serializedEnvelope = DataUtil.createRandomString(200);
when(envelopeSerializer.serialize(envelope)).thenReturn(serializedEnvelope);

// Act
target.send(envelope);

// Assert
verify(outputStream, times(1)).write(AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(serializedEnvelope.getBytes("UTF-8")));
verify(outputStream, atLeastOnce()).flush();
```

The instance of outputStream was created like this:

```
outputStream = mock(OutputStream.class);
```

I'm using the same method for transform the string (which is the same instance, since the mocked **envelopeSerializer** class returns it) into a UTF-8 byte array. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
outputStream.write(
    [102, 100, 104, 54, 111, 104, 55, 99, 51, 101, 120, 119, 99, 114, 50,     120, 104, 98, 98, 51, 99, 48, 120, 106, 55, 114, 102, 114, 102, 103, 50, 111, 108, 122, 109, 119, 117, 100, 50, 102, 114, 112, 51, 109, 114, 121, 49, 114, 104, 104, 103, 101, 104, 112, 54, 48, 54, 122, 98, 101, 113, 100, 54, 116, 51, 102, 106, 56, 118, 99, 102, 52, 98, 98, 105, 114, 111, 112, 111, 52, 102, 56, 97, 107, 51, 98, 107, 105, 119, 49, 117, 97, 98, 99, 48, 55, 53, 121, 102, 101, 50, 105, 117, 110, 115, 112, 112, 102, 53, 100, 54, 120, 117, 115, 117, 105, 99, 105, 109, 111, 100, 111, 122, 101, 57, 116, 102, 110, 55, 114, 52, 97, 114, 55, 48, 49, 113, 51, 97, 116, 57, 115, 110, 112, 55, 52, 106, 111, 101, 121, 112, 54, 100, 112, 111, 56, 102, 52, 115, 51, 99, 98, 99, 98, 102, 118, 107, 57, 99, 48, 98, 114, 111, 111, 115, 111, 120, 119, 106, 101, 103, 102, 99, 116, 98, 98, 114, 109, 110, 116, 113, 97, 53, 120, 52, 113, 111, 114, 118, 110]
);
-> at     org.limeprotocol.network.tcp.TcpTransportTest.send_validArgumentsAndOpenStreamAndTraceEnabled_callsWriteAndTraces(TcpTransportTest.java:98)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
outputStream.write(
    [102, 100, 104, 54, 111, 104, 55, 99, 51, 101, 120, 119, 99, 114, 50, 120, 104, 98, 98, 51, 99, 48, 120, 106, 55, 114, 102, 114, 102, 103, 50, 111, 108, 122, 109, 119, 117, 100, 50, 102, 114, 112, 51, 109, 114, 121, 49, 114, 104, 104, 103, 101, 104, 112, 54, 48, 54, 122, 98, 101, 113, 100, 54, 116, 51, 102, 106, 56, 118, 99, 102, 52, 98, 98, 105, 114, 111, 112, 111, 52, 102, 56, 97, 107, 51, 98, 107, 105, 119, 49, 117, 97, 98, 99, 48, 55, 53, 121, 102, 101, 50, 105, 117, 110, 115, 112, 112, 102, 53, 100, 54, 120, 117, 115, 117, 105, 99, 105, 109, 111, 100, 111, 122, 101, 57, 116, 102, 110, 55, 114, 52, 97, 114, 55, 48, 49, 113, 51, 97, 116, 57, 115, 110, 112, 55, 52, 106, 111, 101, 121, 112, 54, 100, 112, 111, 56, 102, 52, 115, 51, 99, 98, 99, 98, 102, 118, 107, 57, 99, 48, 98, 114, 111, 111, 115, 111, 120, 119, 106, 101, 103, 102, 99, 116, 98, 98, 114, 109, 110, 116, 113, 97, 53, 120, 52, 113, 111, 114, 118, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  
(+ a lot of zeros)
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
0,
200
);
```

Seems like the **verify** method for the mocked **outputStream** instance is checking the value of the parameter against an internal buffer, with the length of 8192 items. The generated class for the mocked OutputStream is **OutputStream$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$b1c65902**.

Any ideas how can I verify if the write method has been called with the correct value with Mockito?

Comment: I don't understand, what is the correct value? If you expect any array of byte starting with 102, 100, ... then a custom matcher is the way to go. Also note that a `ByteArrayOutputStream` might help and avoid a mock here.

Comment: Yes, I could use a ByteArrayOutputStream, but there's no way to do that with Mockito without using a custom matcher?

Comment: I'm affraid there's no magic here, either a custom "starting with" matcher or feed `verify` a 8192-sized array

Answer (score 8):

Instead of mocking the OutputStream, it is simpler to provide one. especially for text.

```
outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.write("Hello World".getBytes());

assertEquals("Hello World", outputStream.toString());
```

If you want to check for a flush() you could do

```
boolean[] flushed = { false };
outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        super.flush();
        flushed[0] = true;
    }
};
```